# how to remove routing in a separate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

how it is possible to remove this routing in a separate component? I tried to do it through the map but it did not work

**I want only one route to remain and when you click on a certain link, 'path' changes in it**

```
const Home = ({ code }) => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper__flex_main">
      <TheNav  {...code} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Main code={code} />} />
        <Route path='/search' element={<TheSearchTrack code={code} />} />
        <Route path='/likes' element={<Likes code={code} />} />
        <Route path='/artist' element={<Artist code={code} />} />
        <Route path="/genre/:id" element={<GenreTemplate code={code} />} />
        <Route path="/artist/:id" element={<ArtistPages code={code} />} />
        <Route path="/genretrack/:id" element={<GenreTrack code={code} />} />
        <Route path="/track/:id" element={<Track code={code} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post to make it clearer what you are trying to do and what exactly any issues are you have with the code. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const loginHandler = () => {
  ...  business logic ...

  // if logic true
  navigate('navigate-path', { replace: true }); // redirect!!!
};
```

You can use something like this , this prevent user navigation to other pages